# Convert OUTER APPLY To Oracle 11g statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, lateral-join

I have the following TSQL,

```
select 2*EC.Total C1, T1.C2, EC.Total
FROM MyTable1 T1 
OUTER APPLY (select COUNT(*) AS Total from MyTable2 T2 WHERE T1.SomeColumn=T2.SomeColumn ) EC
ORDER BY EC.Total desc
```

I need to convert this to Oracle 11g. I tried lateral but not supported.

Comment: I cannot access T1 inside cross join? because it's saying invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need  a lateral join there:

```
select 2*EC.Total C1, T1.C2, EC.Total
FROM MyTable1 T1 
  LEFT JOIN (
    select m2.somecolumn, COUNT(*) AS Total 
    from MyTable2 m2
    group by m2.somecolumn
  ) ec ON t1.somecolumn = ec.somecolumn
ORDER BY EC.Total desc
```